# How to modify the angular ng- tags input plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am getting the below error when ng-tags input autocomplete function try to display the same name twice..

I mean if I give "R" in input box two rob are there means, I am getting the below error,

**Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: item in suggestionList.items track by track(item),**

I knew that ng-repeat wont accept duplicates but I don't how to modify the plugin to accept the duplicates.

The plugin that I am using is ng-tags input , https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/blob/master/src/tags-input.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you need to change the plugin? the home page shows it working http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/

> variable in expression track by tracking_expression

from the doumentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

```
<ul ng-repeat="item in items track by $id(item)">
 ...
```

Comment: Can you please tell where in home page they have mentioned that the plugin will allow duplicates because I am not able to see it.  <ul ng-repeat="item in items track by $id(item)"> is the line present in ng documentation

Answer (score 0):

I've been getting the same error for days now and Ive been trying to figure out without changing the source code for the 3rd party directive how to fix the error in question.

After I select a few items which become tags in the autocomplete textbox then delete the first tag item or any tag item in the middle of the collection I get the same error, "Duplicated in repeater" so this is an error that can happen but I'm not 100% certain as of yet if it is a bug or if it is something I am doing incorrectly with the workflow or life cycle events of the directive expectations.

I am passing in "id" for the key-property directive scope property needed to prevent this error from happening which is stated in the Github issues. The other odd thing is it doesn't happen every single time. Its sort of random.